# Getting resources works from NetBeans Execution Context but not working when jar is executed from comand line

Tags: java, image, netbeans, jar, resources

I have a code where i create Java Actions and try to associate Icons with them. One snapshot of code is

```
FileOpenCommand fileOpen = new FileOpenCommand(this);
fileOpen.putValue("ImageOnly", false);
fileOpen.putValue(Action.NAME, "Open");

fileOpen.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../resources/File-Open-icon24x24.png")));        

fileOpen.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Opens the existing file.");
fileOpen.putValue("Group", "File");
fileOpen.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));

this.commands.put("FileOpen", fileOpen);
```

The accent is on the line where I try to set the Action.SMALL_ICON property to the action. This works when executed in NetBeans environment either in debug or release mode. But when I've tried to execute jar file from the command line, it fails with exception.

Any idea? Anything to do with classpath? Resources folder is put as the package inside the main package.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is the resource in the JAR?

Comment: Yes , it is. The main package is controllz.mmi and the resources package is controllz.mmi.resources. 5he class, which is trying to reach resource is in controllz.mmi.models package. As said its working from beans IDE (both RUN & DEBUG) but not from command line with java -jar Controllz_MMI.jar. Jar file is put to "dest" subfolder of beans project and I try to run it from there...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what exception is being thrown in your case, although assuming it is a `NullPointerException`, `IOException`, or `IllegalArgumentException` deriving from

```
fileOpen.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("../resources/File-Open-icon24x24.png")));
```

Your issue should be resolved simply by adding `getClassLoader()` between the `getClass()` and `getResource()`, like so:

```
fileOpen.putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON, new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("../resources/File-Open-icon24x24.png")));
```

Additionally, you must be exact in your filenames, specifically the extension. In this case, you are accessing `File-Open-icon24x24.png`, which will work perfectly fine regardless of whether the actual file is extended by `png` or `PNG` within Netbeans, but once exported the extension case matters.

Lastly, if neither of those changes resolve your problem, I would check your filepath, as there is most likely a logical error somewhere down the line.

When using embedded resources in Netbeans, you should have a resources folder containing additional folder or whatever data you need, which you seem to have, but this folder should be located inside the Netbeans project's `src` folder. `getClass().getResource()` returns the directory at the top of the package line, meaning if your class package is `com.example.code`, then the compiler will look for files/folder on the same level as `com`. Opening the Netbeans `src` folder you should see the initial `com` folder. Your resource folder should be placed directly next to that folder, as then it will be properly embedded in the `jar` file export.

In your code your path is `../resources/File-Open-icon24x24.png`, which confuses me as to why you begin with `..`. I cannot see your folder structure so I cannot give a precise answer on this note, but you may be accessing the wrong location, although I feel like you are not as you said your project runs correctly within Netbeans. However, your resource files may not be correctly encoding into the `jar` file due to placement as mentioned. To test what your `jar` file actually contains, make a copy of it (for safety reasons) and change the file extension from `jar` to `zip`. You can then look through its contents in Windows Explorer, and see its directory structure. Another debugging trick for folder structures is to create a text file at the `URL` you are trying to access to see where it is placed.